How to use \isnumeric function provided by the "coolstr" package?
I meet a problem when use \isnumeric function in coolstring package. After compilation with pdflatex engine, nothing is output in pdf file. Below is the code.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{coolstr}

\begin{document}

%booleandeclaration

\newboolean{numeric}

\isnumeric{123}{numeric}

\end{document}


coolstr had its time, you can do better now with the expl3 language. For example coolstr will provide false for +123 or -123.

\isnumeric just changes the content of the bool, but won't print anything. You can then use the bool for tests etc.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{coolstr}
\newboolean{numeric}

\begin{document}

\isnumeric{1a23}{numeric}

\ifthenelse{\boolean{numeric}}{
  yes
}{
  no
}

\isnumeric{123}{numeric}

\ifthenelse{\boolean{numeric}}{
  yes
}{
  no
}

\end{document}


This is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz

@XCN You're welcome!
